# disable continue/next button jquery steps with angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-steps

I need to disable the continue button of jquery steps until I meet the exact condition..
ex: without filling username user can not allow to continue(simply disable it).

In angular context how can I do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `template driven forms`. There are key concepts to master when you're doing Angular 2 development and this is one of them. It will take some time but it's well worth the effort: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

So based on this, if you were to create a form element that encapsulates all the fields and add the `required` attribute to the elements that need to be filled (ex: userName), then the button will be disabled if any of the required fields is not filled.

Example input with `required` attribute:

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName"
           required
           [(ngModel)]="yourModel.yourProperty" name="userName"
           #userName ="ngModel">
```

Example button inside your form:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use forms and you're in a rush right now, you can bind to the button's `disabled` attribute and execute a method that returns a boolean after checking whether all the required fields are there or not.

```
<button [disabled]="!isMissingRequiredFields()">Continue</button>
```

And you should use `ngModel` bindings for all the input fields that are required and that you'll be checking in `isMissingRequiredFields()` method so you don't end up doing anything funky like accessing DOM elements from inside your component ts file and getting their innerText etc.

Comment: hi muzurBurcu..this is not just a simple reactive form.I use jquery steps plugin [link](http://www.jquery-steps.com) and need to have a on step validation to next button